# How to convert Date in String to Sql date?

Tags: java, mysql, date-format

I have a date with String format "09-06-2011". I need to compare it with another date in java.sql.Date format "2011-06-30 00:00:00". How can I convert a String date to a sql date ?

Comment: This is a question we usually see and answer on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_to_date` function in MySQL.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Format:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
    -> '2013-05-01'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and its parse method.  Be sure to `setLenient(false)`.